# Permission denied during "cargo build"

Tags: rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rust-cargo, permission-denied

I tried

```sh
cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release
```

to build the [`rust-counter-tutorial`](https://github.com/smiley717/rust-counter-tutorial), and I get the error

```sh
error: failed to open: /home/[...]/target/release/.cargo.lock

Caused by:
  Permission denied (os error 13)
```

I'm very new to coding so bear with me.
I am on WSL Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6757

Comment: Sometimes I get this using CLion. Make sure you don't have your code running when you build.

Comment: When you are running the rust file are you running it as `./<rust file name>`? Always run it as `./<rust file name>`